# Bind Menuitems to a collection, make them checkable and style the

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to bind the subitems of a menu to a collection and then be able to style them and make them selectable in the way of a radiobutton (Only one should be selected at a time). This is what I have so far

```
<MenuItem Header="League" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLeagues}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header"
          Value="{Binding InAppName}" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
```

It works so far that all the items in the collection are visible as menuitems. But I can't apply a style to them and i can't make them checkable. The "MenuItemStyle" only applies to the outer menu item but not to the children.

Do i have to redefine the popup of the outer menuitem to something like a list of radiobuttons(wouldn't know exactly how to do this)  or is there a solution with menuitems?
Thx in advance

Comment: What if you define the style in `<MenuItem.Resources>`, and give it a TargetType: `<Style TargetType="MenuItem">`? No key though, so it's implicit. That should apply then to all menu items in that menu.

Comment: Thx for your help. But the same problem like in the other answer appeared. The outer menuitem is checkable and doesn't expand. I solved it now by binding a converter to "IsCheckable". It returns false for the outer menu and true for the children. Still feels like a hack.

Comment: ohhh right -- I think you need to set IsCheckable to false in a trigger if HasItems, sorry! I think you can't have both.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thx again. The solution with the trigger works great. I don't need an extra converter class this way. Learned a lot again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method applies a style to a MenuItem and all of its children, and their children, recursively:

```
<MenuItem Header="Main Menu Item">
    <MenuItem Header="Unaffected Sibling" />

    <MenuItem Header="Foo">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding InAppName}" />
                <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsSomeRandomBoolProperty}" />

                <Setter Property="Background" Value="YellowGreen" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem Header="Bar" />
        <MenuItem Header="I Am Damo Suzuki">
            <MenuItem Header="Blah blah blah">
                <MenuItem Header="Amon Duul II" />
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thx but it doesn't work completely. If I set "IsCheckable" to true, then the menuitem doesn't expand and shows it's children. I need a MenuItem which is bound to a collection and then it's children must be checkable, not the menuitem itself. Thy styling part works. Maybe i try to bind the IsCheckable also to the InAppName and use a converter on it which returns true for the main item and false for the children. But this feels like a hack rather then a good solution..

Comment: It works now. '<Style TargetType="MenuItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuSubItemStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding InAppName }" />
                        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding InAppName, Mode=OneWay, Converter= {StaticResource LeagueNameToCheckable}}" />
                    </Style>'   I dont know how to insert code into a comment but I did it with the converter. Thx again

Comment: @RichardLoth Awesome